How can I update the email in firebase authentication?
I am looking to update the firebase email in the authentication. Once I update the email, and if I check back the Firebase Authentication, I am hoping to see the new email. Next time when I try to login, then I can login with the new email, but can use the old password. Is it possible (if at all)?
Code Snippet:
  Future<bool> updateEmail(String newEmail) async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User? user = auth.currentUser;
    try {
      await user!.verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(newEmail);
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      if (mounted) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('$e'),
          ),
        );
      
      }
     return false;
  
    }
  }


Renaud's answer shows how you can change the email address for any user in a trusted environment.
If you want the user themselves to be able to change their email address from the Flutter app, you can use verifyBeforeUpdateEmail  for that.

I tried that but the new email does not get registered in the authentication page in firebase. I want the user to have the new email for logging in next time. May be I am doing it wrong.

Maybe you are indeed, but without seeing a minimal repro it's hard to be sure.

I have added the code snippet. The value saved from Textfield is passed on to a function to update email. No error is shown, but when I check the authentication in firebase, it doesn't get updated.

okay, I figured it out. Its working now. I have to give a valid email so that I can verify the email received, and it works.

Noted. I faced another roadblock. Once I get a verification email, I want to change the state once it is verified. So the the code I am using is if(user.emailVerified){ then...}. But the issue here is that email is being verified for the previous email that I had - and always gets verified automatically without actually me verifying it. What is the work around for that?

"another roadblock" -> please post another question with its own minimal repro for that.

You can use the Firebase Admin SDK to modify an existing user's data, including it's email, see the documentation.
So, with the user uid and the new email you would do as follows:
admin
  .auth()
  .updateUser(uid, {
    email: 'modifiedUser@example.com'
  })
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully updated user', userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error updating user:', error);
  });

The above code is Node.js code that you can, for example, run in a Cloud Function or even as a Node.js script from you computer (See the section names "For Firestore" of this SO answer for an example).
